# AWS Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

I am trying to authenticate users via AWS Cognito/IAM services from my webapp. I have implemented Facebook and LinkedIn login and I'm wondering how I could use AWS to implement username+password login via my UI. Is there a way for me to set it up so that all I have to do is drop in button for username+password login on my view and that will authenticate users and redirect back to my backend service (similar to Facebook/LinkedIn) and where I can put in an endpoint URL?

Do let me know If I need to be clearer.

Edit1: I have already tried using [Developer Authenticated Workflow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) (enhanced workflow). I don't want to do the part where I create the User in my user pool by calling the AWS Cognito Identity API. I'd like AWS to do the user creation by itself. is this possible?

Edit2: Another alternative solution is to create a Lambda which does what I want. But this is similar to the code to do that (which is on my backend).

Comment: So, we ended up using Auth0 service for this (which is brining it's own set of problems!)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no complete solution for this. You have to either use newly introduced AWS Cognito User Pools or create your own one. I would also recommend to checkout the project https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth which worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can create AWS Cognito user pools and create the roles for authenticated and unauthenticated users and assign some policies for both roles. Once you have created the user pool you will necessary code to use in your web or mobile application. Refer [How to setup Cognito user pools.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html)